# Detecting Caps Lock not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I'm trying to detect if a user is typing into an input field when the Caps Lock button is on. I've started with an input wrapped within a span that performs an `onkeypress` check:

```
<span onkeypress="{!c.keyCheck}">
    <lightning:input aura:id="capsLock" label="test" />
</span>
```

My Controller.js performs a check for the specific key. Since the Caps Lock key's numeric value is 20, I'm passing that into the `keyCheck` method:

```
keyCheck : function(component, event, helper) {
    // Caps Lock numeric value: 20
    if (event.which == 20) {
        var capsLockMessage = component.find("capsLockMessage");
        $A.util.toggleClass(capsLockMessage, "slds-hide");
        alert("Caps Lock was pressed");
    }
}
```

However, this isn't firing. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: can you try to put in div and use `onkeyup="{! c.keyCheck}` event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be onkeypress, but should be onkeyup.

> In theory, the keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed
>   or released, while the keypress event represents a character being
>   typed. The implementation of the theory is not same in all browser

```
<span onkeyup="{!c.keyCheck}">
    <lightning:input aura:id="capsLock" label="test" />
</span>
```

Js:

```
({
    keyCheck : function(component, event, helper) {
    // Caps Lock numeric value: 20
    console.log(event.which);
    if (event.which == 20) {
        var capsLockMessage = component.find("capsLockMessage");
        $A.util.toggleClass(capsLockMessage, "slds-hide");
        alert("Caps Lock was pressed");
    }
}
})
```

Src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown

Comment: Thanks, Pranay! That works!